# intersperse function in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm looking for an equivalent of the haskell instersperse function  in Ruby. Basically that add something (like a separator) between each element of a list.

```
intersperse(nil, [1,2,3]) => [1,nil,2,nil,3,nil,4].
```

I'm not asking for any code (I can do it , and I'd probably have done it before you read the question). I'm just wondering if a such function already exists on the standard Ruby platform.

#### update

I'm not asking for any code, and especially ones using flatten, as that doesn't work (flatten does not only flat one level but all).
I gave the example [1,2,3] just as example, but it should work with

```
 [[1,2],[3,4]].interperse("hello") => [[1,2], "hello", [3,4]]
```

(Please don't send me any code to make that it work , I have it already

```
class Array
  def intersperse(separator)
    (inject([]) { |a,v|  a+[v,separator] })[0...-1]
  end
end
```

)

Comment: I'm tempted to tag this `plz-dont-send-teh-codez`!

Comment: @andrew: I would simply tag it `plz-read-question` ;-)

Comment: *flatten does not only flat one level but all* -- Not true. You specificy the maximum flattening level as an optional argument. See my answer for an example.

Comment: @Jorg: point taken, however pretty much all of the answers didn't use this optional parameter. I thought It didn't because the (doc)[http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002218] (first google hit) doesn't mention it (so I voted for your answer).

Comment: Those are the docs for Ruby 1.8.6 (released 2007-03-13). Both Ruby 1.9.0 (released 2007-12-28) and Ruby 1.8.7 (released 2008-06-01) have it. See http://RDoc.Info/docs/ruby-core/1.8.7/Array#flatten-instance_method and http://RDoc.Info/docs/ruby-core/1.9.2/Array#flatten-instance_method

Comment: @Jorg: Thanks , I just did a google , and,  as no version number appears in the URL , I thought It would be  the official  up-to-date  Ruby doc. Anyway we are still using Rubi 1.8.6 at work in some places.

Comment: Relevant feature request: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/16946

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No

Comment: Would adding a full stop make the answer too verbose? :)

Comment: This is really the only question that answers the question that was actually asked; not the question that people thought was asked. Upvoted. `join` is probably the closest "thematically."

Answer (score 8):

No, not that I know of. But you can always [check yourself](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html).

The only similar method (by the way: Ruby is an object-oriented language, there is no such thing as a "function" in Ruby) is `Array#join`, which maps the elements to strings and interperses them with a separator. `Enumerable#intersperse` would basically be a generalization of that.

Like you said, it's trivial to implement, for example like this:

```
module Enumerable
  def intersperse(obj=nil)
    map {|el| [obj, el] }.flatten(1).drop(1)
  end
end
```

or this:

```
module Enumerable
  def intersperse(obj=nil)
    drop(1).reduce([first]) {|res, el| res << obj << el }
  end
end
```

Which would then make `Array#join` simply a special case:

```
class Array
  def join(sep=$,)
    map(&:to_s).intersperse(s ||= sep.to_str).reduce('', :<<)
  end
end
```

Comment: I love how the question explicitly states *not* to post an implementation, and *only* answer the question whether such a method already exists, and all three answers ignore the request and two out of three don't even answer the question :-)

Comment: Because when people ask questions like this, they never really seem happy with a "No" answer - and besides, it's not enough characters :)

Comment: By offering an alternative, it is an implied "no". But what's the fun in answering a yes/no question that as you say, can be checked in a few seconds?

Comment: just out of curiosity, if ruby doesn't have functions, whats a lambda?

Comment: @gnibbler, i would have been happy with a "No". Guess I have to answer it mylself and accept my own no ;-)

Comment: @mark it could be check in a few second , only if the answer is yes. No finding it in the doc doesn't mean anything exist.

Comment: @Jörg: Do you think there should be a feature request for intersperse?

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: I'm thinking about it. I've also been looking at `Enumerable#scan`. In fact, I may just read the entire [ScalaDocs](http://Scala-Lang.Org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/scala/collection/immutable/Traversable.html) and [Haddocks](http://Haskell.Org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Data-List.html) for Scala's and Haskell's collections libraries, and check out which of the missing functionality makes sense for Ruby. We already have Scala's `flatMap` in Ruby 1.9.2 as `Enumerable#flat_map` / `Enumerable#concat_collect`.

Comment: @Jorg: That's great, I'm not sure my boss (and the team) will be happy if I start using it.

Answer (score 2):

Seems similar to zip...

Maybe something like this:

```
class Array
  def intersperse(item)
    self.zip([item] * self.size).flatten[0...-1]
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
[1,2,3].intersperse(nil) #=> [1, nil, 2, nil, 3]
```

Comment: This isn't quite right. Try passing something other than `nil` - it's only used in the first spot. The rest _default_ to `nil`. You can fix it by using `item.cycle`

Comment: You're right! I can't believe this sat for 5 years before someone noticed the bug. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I came here with the same question and gathered that the answer is still "no", but wanted to dream-up a more efficient implementation. Came up with these mutative and non-mutative approaches:

```rb
class Array
  def intersperse!(separator)
    (1..((size - 1) * 2)).step(2).each { |i| insert i, separator }
    self
  end

  def intersperse(separator)
    a = []
    last_i = size - 1
    each_with_index do |elem, i|
      a << elem
      a << separator unless i == last_i
    end
    a
  end
end
```